# How to resize image before_save with dragonfly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dragonfly-gem

In my model i have:

```
attr_accessible :photo
image_accessor :photo
before_save :resize_image

def resize_image
  self.photo = self.photo.process(:resize, '40x40')
end
```

but after save it removes my photo_uid from record in database (or doesnt write photo_uid at all)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

huh, i found:

```
image_accessor :photo do
   after_assign :resize_image
end

def resize_image
   photo.process!(:resize, '1000x650>')
end
```

Comment: What about specs? I get the following error when I run rspecs after adding the above code: `None of the functions registered with #<Dragonfly::Processor:0xb1443ac> were able to deal with the method call resize(<Dragonfly::TempObject data="/consequuntur.png" >,"200x50"). You may need to register one that can.`

Comment: In later versions of dragonfly `image_accessor` has changed to `dragonfly_accessor` and `:resize` process to `:thumb`.